# Sendmail queueing and not sending local mail promptly

Tags: sendmail

OS: 2.6.32-696.23.1.el6.x86_64 (Centos 6)

Sendmail: 8.14.4

sendmail will receive mail for local users from outside users but queue it and not deliver it promptly but in spurts; 
sample receipt line:

> Nov  1 15:56:17 server sendmail[18406]: wA1JqHk8018406: to=, delay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=83669, dsn=4.4.3, stat=queued

Then:

> Nov  1 22:50:31 server sendmail[19747]: wA1JqHk8018406: to=, delay=06:54:14, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=713669, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent

At that time 27 other messeges were marked as 'stat=Sent'.

Any useful sendmail commands to debug this one? Things to check in the .mc or .cf files?

I should mention that I am getting the following message in the initial transaction:

> Nov  1 15:56:18 server sendmail[18406]: STARTTLS: write error=syscall error (-1), errno=104, get_error=error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), retry=99, ssl_err=5

There's not much I can find about this error, except to use ssldump. I don't know whether it is relevant to the main problem.

Comment: Could you post `DeliveryMode` option and `Mlocal` (local mailer) lines from your `/etc/mail/sendmail.cf` file?

Comment: check out the DSN error codes [here](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3463.txt).

Comment: `ssl_err=5` suggests it's related to certificates and encryption. Hard to answer with the lack of details.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to dig through the .cf file and the .config file and edit lines  like

```
QUEUE_INTERVAL="10m";
```

If you set enough of these low hopefully it will fix the speed setting.

To debug have one window with command below running

```
while true; do mailq; sleep 1s; done
```

check how fast things enter and leave the q
Try running with wire shark capturing the network session on your sender and receiver this will help you determine whether there is network latency involved.

try running with these flags

```
-N 'delay, success, failure'
-X logfile.log
-bv
```

Also try

```
postconf readme_directory or postconf html_directory
```

In order to find the DEBUG_README Which is very useful for Debugging

Comment: Default sendmail configuration conducts "at once" delivery attempts.